# css vertical height with position: absolute

Tags: html, css, positioning

i have this simplified skeleton structure:

```
<div id='parent">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="child-1"></div>
        <div id="child-2"></div>
        <div id="child-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the parent div to expand to the height of the tallest child. I can do that no problem as long as the children are not position: absolute which is what i need them to be.

When the children are set to absolute, the parent's height is no longer affected by the height of the children.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: Not really. You could try positioning them using `position: relative` if you're not moving them very far. But the point of absolute positioning is that it removes the element from the flow of the page.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options in this situation.

The first is to use { position: relative } instead of absolute. This keeps the elements in the flow of the page and the parent will render with the size you're looking for.

The other option is to use a bit of javascript to find the size of each child, determine which is largest, and then set the parent to that height.

```
var children = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('div');

var max_child_height = 0;
for(i = 0; i < children.length ; i++){
    if(children[i].offsetHeight > max_child_height) {
        max_child_height = children[i].offsetHeight;
    }
}

document.getElementById('parent').height = max_child_height;
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the child-N element are positioned side by side. While you do this using absolute positioning you could also do this using float:left. This way (after clearing) the parent will have the height of the highest child element.

```
#child-1, #child-2, #child3 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
/* now clear the float, otherwise #content would have no height*/
#content {
  overflow:hidden;/*normal browsers*/
  zoom:1;/*IE fix*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for solving this problem. 
Or position:relative
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Tallest
It might be useful